# Setting background color on toast makes it rectangular

Tags: android

If I set the background color of my `Toast` with

```
            t.getView().setBackgroundColor(
                    ctx.getResources().getColor(R.color.myorange));
```

the new (Android 4.4) rounded Toast becomes rectangular. Any way to prevent this apart from using a custom rounded background `Drawable`?

[image]

[image]

Comment: afaik you will have to make a round drawable yourself, but that takes like 2 minutes, searching fpr another alternative might take hours? worth it? =D

Comment: I kinda like the rectangle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to prevent that.  The default background for the toast is a drawable that defines the rounded corners.  If you want rounded corners in a different color, you'll have to define your own shape drawable.

Comment: Example please, including tying the drawable object to the the toast object programmatically (no xml files).

Answer (score 4):

Do not try to set the background color directly, set a color filter instead. That will preserve the toast shape:

```
int backgroundColor = ResourcesCompat.getColor(t.getView().getResources(), R.color.myorange, null);
t.getView().getBackground().setColorFilter(backgroundColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```