# Create 9patch with fully round sides

Tags: android, nine-patch

I'm trying to create a drawable that looks like the KitKat toast bacground:

[image]

but I have no idea how to recreate the fully round sides, I always end up with a rectangle with rounded edges like this:

[image]

or the sides aren't really round:

[image]

Any idea on how to accomplish this?

Btw, just setting the color of the Toast [doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20999064/setting-background-color-on-toast-makes-it-rectangular).

Comment: Try adding your content area (right edge) to full (all black).

Comment: plase give me your image witout creating ninepatch.

Comment: I'm guessing it's a shape

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do it like this:

[image: holo toast background from API 19]

This is the toast_frame_holo.9.png from Android-19 (HDPI)

Comment: Where did you find this resource?

Comment: If you have the SDK install, it is in [SDK-DIR]/platforms/android-19/data/res/drawable-[density]/

Answer (score 7):

[Android 9-patch shadow generator](http://inloop.github.io/shadow4android/)
will help you achieve the desired 9patch, allowing you to customize the roundness of the sides to your liking.
[image]

"Fill & Outline" will also give you the ability to apply some color.