# Showing a Snackbar from inside a Service

Tags: android, android-layout, service, android-snackbar

When showing a `SnackBar` from inside an `Activity`, I have the `rootView` available. But I need to show a `SnackBar` from inside a `Service`, where I do not have a `View` available. How might I accomplish this?

As backstory: an activity starts a service to do a task. The `Service` needs to show a `SnackBar` depending on situations. I don’t want to Bind to the `Service` just for that. So how might I accomplish this? Normally I could show a `Toast`, but I need the user to be able to read the message and confirm so.

Comment: To clarify, are you asking about being able to show the Snackbar while the user is using the app, or anytime, even if the app is closed?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The [`Snackbar`](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/support/design/widget/Snackbar.html) needs a [`View`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) to be displayed, so if you want to show snackbars on your app depending on the state of your [`Service`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) you'll have to either bind it to your [`Activity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) or broadcast a message through the [`LocalBroadcastManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html) and show a message on your `View`.

I don't think there's any other way around it, you'll have to communicate with your `Activity` or `Fragment` somehow.

**Snackbars are not like Toasts that only need a context**, so if you want to display it out of your app, I believe you can't with the class provided by Android.

As from the [design guidelines](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/snackbars-toasts.html):

> **Placement**
>
> Snackbars appear above most elements on screen, and they are equal in
>   elevation to the floating action button. However, they are lower in
>   elevation than dialogs, bottom sheets, and navigation drawers.

It's not explicit, but you can reach the conclusion that it'll only display inside your app views. So, again, you'll have to communicate with your **visible** view somehow.

---

Snippets on broadcasting a message:

**Sender (on your Service)**

```
private void doSendBroadcast(String message) {
    Intent it = new Intent("EVENT_SNACKBAR");

    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(message))
        it.putExtra(EXTRA_RETURN_MESSAGE,message);

    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(mContext).sendBroadcast(it);
}
```

**Receiver (on your Activity)**

```
private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Other stuff.

    mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // Do something
        }
    };
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter("EVENT_SNACKBAR"));
}
```

More on bound services [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html).

And about `LocalBroadcastManager` [here on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802157/how-to-use-localbroadcastmanager).

**Update:** You could also make use of an [EventBus](http://greenrobot.org/eventbus) to communicate with your *visible* view, as it works on a Publisher/Subscriber fashion. You could even make use of the concept of [Sticky events](http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/documentation/configuration/sticky-events/) to make sure the `Snackbar` will be displayed once the app is visible again.

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47147833/access-the-results-of-a-started-service-from-two-different-activities-in-android/47148006#47148006) of mine on how to use the Event Bus.

Answer (score 5):

You could always send a broadcast through the [`LocalBroadcastManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html) in your `Service`

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(new Intent("SERVICE_DID_SOMETHING"));
```

And then in the `Activity` use a [`BroadcastReceiver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) to show the `Snackbar`

```
private final ServiceReceiver _serviceReceiver = new ServiceReceiver();

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    final IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction("SERVICE_DID_SOMETHING");

    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(_serviceReceiver, intentFilter);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    try {
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(_serviceReceiver);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error unregistering ServiceReceiver", ex);
    }
}

// region ServiceReceiver
private class ServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO: Show your Snackbar here...
    }
}
// endregion
```

You can use the `Intent` you send to pass additional data if needed and then pull it out in the `BroadcastReceiver.onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)`

Comment: Thanks for your help. +1. I can only accept one answer, so I flipped a coin. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

How to create a Snackbar with the application context which is visible across multiple activities: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37707741/1185087

Answer (score -1):

It is not possible to do it with the default `SnackBar` provided by the SDK, since it will always require a view.

To serve your purpose you can use some external library which mimics a SnackBar like [this one](https://github.com/MrEngineer13/SnackBar)

Comment: would appreciate a reason when someone downvotes unless it is by competing answers seeking attention. :)

Comment: That tends to happen a lot in here. I hate it, it's not constructive.

Comment: No, @AndroidMechanic, you must have to pass a view to SnackBar provided with the SDK or this library.

You will be able to find 2 constructors.

#1 `new SnackBar.Builder(this)` - `this` as activity.

#1 `new SnackBar.Builder(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), root)` - `root` as view root