# Tell user they are off-line across entire app

Tags: android

Is there a way to display some sort of warning view across all of my app when the user does not have internet access? Maybe even have a way for the user to enable wifi or a mobile data connection from that warning view / dialog?

I'm trying to avoid having to copy paste some sort of dialog warning to every activity in my app.

Comment: I think you can use a BaseActivity and do what you want(display some sort of warning view) in it, and all your activity extends it. not only fit for this situation, the BaseActivity is also used for other duplicated code.

Comment: look this. It may help. http://stackoverflow.com/a/37707741/5241603

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build the logic to display and hide the warning into a Fragment, and just include the fragment in each Activity.  No copy paste needed (or at least, just 1 line in each activity's main xml file).